# Why doesn't lcov report exception coverage?

Tags: objective-c, lcov

Refer to [this coverage report](http://jasperblues.github.com/Typhoon/coverage/Source/Factory/TyphoonComponentFactory.m.gcov.html) . . I know that my test cases are exercising the exception handling, however the lines are still being reported as not covered. . . This has been the case in all of my objective-c projects for a while now. . . . is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you compiling with no optimization and no inline?