# Why aren't scopes that throw exceptions showing as covered in gcov/CoverStory?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gcov, coverstory

I'm using the coverage tools in Xcode 4.6 and visualizing with CoverStory. No matter what I do, CoverStory never shows scopes in which I throw Objective-C exceptions as being covered, even though, when running the Unit Tests with breakpoints on those lines, I hit the breakpoints, and the tests (which expect the throws) all pass.

Is there some setting I need to set to make the coverage tools see this?

EDIT: I found CoverStory's exclusion flags [here.](http://code.google.com/p/coverstory/wiki/NonFeasibleCode) Still seems odd to me that it doesn't see this line as getting executed. Why is that?

Comment: It's not CoverStory that is failing to present this information, the gcov tool is simply not recording it.

I use the lcov system to present coverage reports in HTML format (so that I can have the build server present them, or upload them to a GitHub page), and noticed exactly the same problem.

Comment: Asked the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796711/why-doesnt-lcov-report-exception-coverage